# Database update in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need some help, cause i cant understand why this code dont work... I can select name, price and in_stock from database, but after when i want to update them, dont work it.

```
 include("../db_config.php");
 $tipus=$_POST['tipus'];  
 $meret=$_POST['meret'];  
 $ar=$_POST['ar'];
 $submit=$_POST['sb']; 
 $up=$_POST['up'];


if(!empty($submit) && !empty($up)){

     $sql[0]="UPDATE products SET tipus='$name',meret='$price',ar='$in_stock' WHERE id= '$up' "; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql[0]);  
    if(mysqli_error($conn)) {
        header("Location: news.php?mode=adds&msg=Changes couldn't be saved.");
    }
    else {
        header("Location: /news.php?mode=adds&msg=Changes succesfully saved.");
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  What is the actual query being executed at runtime.  (Note: This is *wide open* to **SQL injection** so you don't actually control what's being executed.)  If there's an error coming from the database, why don't you examine that error instead of just ignoring it?  Error messages usually have a way of telling you what the problem is, you should read the message.

Comment: are you getting any error please tell?

Comment: First of all you won't need a $result because you're doing an update. What are you expecting there?


I would write it like this:
`if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Updated";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}`


Maybe you should just echo the $_POST array so you can check yourself if everything is setup alright.

Comment: fixed it, thanks KRONWALLED

Comment: btw, why the `[0]` in `$sql[0]` ? There's no need for it. Plus, you should add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise your code may want to continue executing.

Comment: @RolandFaragó what was the problem?

Comment: I made a mistake in: $sql[0]="UPDATE products SET tipus='$name',meret='$price',ar='$in_stock' WHERE id= '$up' ";